# Subset data.table columns independently

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I'm starting with the below table `dt` and try to subset its column by the list `keys`:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

randomchar <- function(n, w){
  chararray <- replicate(w, sample(c(letters, LETTERS), n, replace = TRUE))
  apply(chararray, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
}

dt <- data.table(x = randomchar(1000, 3),
                 y = randomchar(1000, 3),
                 z = randomchar(1000, 3),
                 key = c("x", "y", "z"))

keys <- with(dt, list(x = sample(x, 501),
              y = sample(y, 500),
              z = sample(z, 721)))
```

I can get the result I want by using a loop:

```
desired <- copy(dt)

for(i in seq_along(keys)){
  keyname <- names(keys)[i]
  desired <- desired[get(keyname) %in% keys[[i]]]
}

desired
```

The question is - **Is there a more data.table idiomatic way to do this subset?**

I tried using `CJ`: `dt[CJ(keys)]`, but it takes a very long time.

Comment: What about creating a new field `key` that concatenates all three keys with `paste` and filter on it?

Comment: I think you mean to use `do.call(CJ, keys)`.

Comment: @Frank Possibly - I just tried it and it completes, but both takes longer and doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Oh right. Hm, seems like `dt[do.call(CJ, keys), nomatch=0]` should work, but it also gives the wrong result... I think there's a FR to make compound tests like `a %in% as & b %in% bs` use keys or indices, but can't find it.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1453

Comment: @Frank nice find, I didn't remember about my comment there, so yes, looks like one wrapper function could allow to use this with performance of indices. I wonder how well it will scale. There is still a place for a other answers.

Comment: not sure but maybe OP code could use indices already.

Comment: @jangorecki Yeah, I was thinking that. Unfortunately, looks like indices get stripped when subsetting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about building a mask and filter `dt` on this mask:

```
dt[Reduce(`&`, Map(function(key, col) col %in% key, keys, dt)),]
```

Comment: This implementation is about twice as fast as mine

Comment: the copy takes a lot of time, whereas here it is just filtering.